# Net::HTTP Start vs New

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, tcp, net-http

Ruby Version: 1.9.3

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net.html
The documentation states that "If you wish to re-use a connection across multiple HTTP requests without automatically closing it you can use ::new instead of ::start"

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-new
This documentation states that "Creates a new Net::HTTP object without opening a TCP connection or HTTP session. "

Scenario:

My aim is use re-use HTTP and TCP connections as much as possible. If i am using Net::HTTP.start as my HTTP object, and if there is a significant delay between two successive calls ( > 2 minutes), the first call after the delay is failing with EOFError : end of file reached.

So, I am planning to swap Net::HTTP.start with Net::HTTP.new

Questions:

If i use new instead of start, will new re-use connections? or will it try to create a new HTTP and TCP connection everytime a HTTP call is made?

Will there be a performance impact because of this?
What is the best way to handle in scenarios like these, where we want to make HTTP calls in a high volume traffic?

Answer (score 6):

I have not tested it myself, but if you read two sentences further in the docs, I think you'll get the answer to your questions.

> If you wish to re-use a connection across multiple HTTP requests without automatically closing it you can use `::new` instead of `::start`. **`request` will automatically open a connection to the server if one is not currently open. You can manually close the connection with `finish`.**

So if you want to keep the connection alive between requests, you can do something like:

```
begin
  http = Net::HTTP.new('example.com')
  http.start
  response1 = http.get('path1')
  response2 = http.get('path2')
ensure
  http.finish
end
```

(using the begin / ensure block so that the connection is guaranteed to close, even if an exception occurs since opening it).

The same can be achieved more easily using a block with the `start` method:

```
Net::HTTP.start('example.com') do |http|
  response1 = http.request_get('path1')
  response2 = http.request_get('path2')
end
```

Yes, keep-alive connection will indeed be faster as there is no need to do the TCP handshakes needed to set up and close the TCP connection.

Also, take a look at this wonderful [blog post about using the pipe-lining feature](https://www.igvita.com/2011/10/04/optimizing-http-keep-alive-and-pipelining/) of HTTP1.1 which, if supported by the server, may greatly enhance performance. But I guess properly supporting pipe-lining at the server end is rather an advanced technique.